# python discord bot ban command

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to coding in python and I don't exactly know how to run a ban command yet, I've tried using tons of templates but nothing seems to work, I know I'm probably just being dumb but can someone help? by the way I'm using replit's import discord stuff because I'm lazy and I didn't want to go through all that trouble.

below is my current code

```html
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%')
#ban
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("you can't the do the does do  the ban this member.")
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = "no reason provided"
    message = f"you got been have the banned have from the {ctx.guild.name} for in the {reason}."
    await member.send(message)
    # await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is now got the have been banned for {reason}")
```

Comment: also the typos in the ban messages like "you have got been have the banned have from the {ctx.guild.name} for in the {reason}." are intentional, I added them in as an inside joke.

Comment: Have you imported `from discord.ext import commands`?